# Using C# 7.1 default literal in nullable optional argument causes unexpected behavior

Tags: c#, default, nullable, compiler-bug, c#-7.1

C# 7.1 introduces a new feature called "Default Literals" that allows new `default` expressions.

```
// instead of writing
Foo x = default(Foo);

// we can just write
Foo x = default;
```

For `Nullable<T>` types, the default value is `null`, and with the usual usage this works as expected:

```
int? x = default(int?); // x is null

int? x = default; // x is null
```

However, when I try to use the new default literal as an optional argument (parameter) of a function, it's not working as expected:

```
static void Foo(int? x = default(int?))
{
    // x is null
}

static void Foo(int? x = default)
{
    // x is 0 !!!
}
```

To me, this behavior is unexpected and looks like a bug in the compiler.

**Can anybody confirm the bug, or explain this behavior?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After more research online, I found out that it's a **known confirmed bug**:

- https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/970
- https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/22578

It's already [fixed and will be part of C# 7.2](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/pull/22527).