# AutoMapper is mapping false for an optional bool even when the optional bool is null

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a question about a code snippet in my application. x.UsesFeature and Person.UsesFeature are both of type optional bool (bool?).  When src.Person.UsesFeature = null, the right side of the ternary operator will be evaulated. My understanding is that the default value of bool? is null. But when this is done mapping, x.UsesFeature is set to False, not null. Why is this happening?

```
                var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.AddProfile<TestProfile>());
```

.
.
.then when I map the property in that TestProfile class

```
   .ForMember(x => x.UsesFeature, opt =>
            {
                opt.MapFrom(src => src.User.UsesFeature.HasValue ? src.User.UsesFeature.Value : default);
            })
```

Comment: Please provde a [mre] that replicates your problem. See  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3083654/automapper-null-properties and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38237908/automapper-checking-for-null-in-mapfrom

Comment: Check [the execution plan](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Understanding-your-mapping.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an Automapper problem, if you do the below, you'll see that it sets to `false`:

```
bool? foo = null;
var bar = foo.HasValue ? foo.Value : default;
```

However, simply changing the default to `default(bool?)` resolves your issue.

```
bool? foo = null;
var bar = foo.HasValue ? foo.Value : default(bool?);
```

Comment: This seems to be [confirmed as a bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46997896/3034273) in C# 7.1 and later fixed in 7.2.